# how can i retrive images with specific name?

Tags: python, file, shutil

I have a folder containing 82.000 images and a file containing 50.000 names of the images I need, how can I use the name of the file to retrieve the image itself
I tried this

```
import os, os.path
import fnmatch
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import shutil
from shutil import copyfile
from pathlib import Path

dst="/new_folder"
scr="/dataset"
id_ = "name_image.txt"

files = os.listdir(scr)

for img_filename in os.listdir(scr):
    x = os.path.splitext(img_filename)[0].split('jpeg')
    print(x)

with open(id_) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for lines in os.listdir(scr):
        if lines in x:
           shutil.move(os.path.join(scr,lines), dst)
```

but not work

the file contains names in this format

```
dataset_000000112915
dataset_000000112941
```

Comment: Read the file which has names of image files and the process one image at a time.

Comment: i already did it in this line `with open(id_) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import glob
import os

dst="/new_folder"
scr="/dataset"
id_ = "name_image.txt"

with open(id_) as f:
   lines = [x.replace('\n','') for x in f.readlines()]

for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(scr, '*.jpeg'), recursive=True):
   if f.split(os.sep)[-1] in lines:
      os.rename(f, os.path.join(dst, f.split(os.sep)[-1]))
```

Comment: i tried but nothing i got